# Help to find LED Robotic Head components

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, controller

I'm going crazy trying to find this component (Sorry the board is uncleaned full of flux everywhere):

[image: voltage regulators]

At first I thought it was a simple DC-DC controller (voltage regulator) but I have no way to find the equivalent, which is not on top of the chip the ID, I bought a XL7015E1 but the pins are not the same.

What they do is control the intensity of the LEDs in a robotic head, and measured with multimeter I have:

- PIN 1 - 30v DC -> I think it is the voltage input.
- PIN 2 - 1.2v DC -> I think it would be the chip switch.
- PIN 3 - gnd? -> I put it with question mark because it did not give any voltage, it could be ground or null
- PIN 4 - gnd -> I put it with question mark because it didn't give any voltage, it could be ground or null
- PIN 5 - 20v DC -> I think it is the voltage output.

The thing is that all the chips that I find have the PIN 1 as voltage input (correct) but the ON/OFF switch on the 5 and in this case as far as I see it goes on the 2, to see if someone has fought with this and can tell me where to look.

Greetings and thanks!

Edit:

Searching I have come across the following which are a good match, but if you could point me in the best direction I would appreciate it:

- BD3572YFP-ME2 500mA
- BD3575YFP-ME2 500mA
- TLE4252D 250mA
- TLE4251GXT 400 mA
- TLE4251GATMA1 400 mA
- TLE4251DATMA1 400 mA
- TLE4252DATMA1 250 mA

Edit 2:

The package is either TO-252-5 or TO-263-5, so I have been going practically crazy on the component pages filtering for this package and trying to limit the parameters:

- I know it should work on the input at 30V or more which is what they all get.
- The output of the ones that work is 20V.
- It must be activated with a signal of at least 1.2V.
- In the leg 4 it seems that there are some resistors, the truth is that I have not gone that far but I suppose that they will serve to regulate the voltage from 30V input to 20V output.
- I know that the distribution should be:

  - PIN 1: Input voltage
  - PIN 2: On/Off (1.2v is not useful for me for anything else)
  - PIN 3: Ground
  - PIN 4: I thought it was ground but looking at the specs and how it is connected I think it goes to the resistors to regulate voltage.
  - PIN 5: Power output which is connected to the LEDs directly.

Comment: That's not flux, it's a protective coating and might give you some bit of trouble if and when you get to the point of unsoldering/resoldering.

Comment: left solder joint on R18 and right solder joint on R19 look questionable ... could be only the angle of illumination